# How to create a custom directive for ng-table (using different data for the table and ng-repeat)

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I am a little stuck trying to create a custom directive for ng-table.
In my application I have multiple times the table "users". 
I have a main table that displays all the users, and I also have some custom tables that displays a limited number of users.
These custom data for the tables is created into the controllers and have different names (usersList1, usersList2 etc.).

The tables are identical (header, columns labels), only the data inside changes.

I would like to have a custom directive and to pass to it the data to display.

Here is my code:

```
.directive('tableForListingDirective', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            scope: true,
            template: [

                '<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" template-pagination="custom/pager">',
                '<tr ng-repeat="user in tableData">',
                '<td width="30" style="text-align: left" header="\'ng-table/headers/checkbox.html\'"> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="user.checked" ng-change="toggleCheckedUserToAdd(user)"/>',
                '<td data-title="\'Status\'" sortable="\'status\'">{{user.status}}</td>',
                '<td data-title="\'Login\'" sortable="\'login\'">{{user.login}}</td>',
                '<td data-title="\'Name\'" sortable="\'name\'">{{user.name}}</td>',
                '<td data-title="\'Email\'" sortable="\'email\'">{{user.email}}</td>',
                '</tr>',
                '</table>'
            ].join(''),
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.tableData=scope.$eval(attrs.tableData);
            },
        }
    });
```

Call in the html file:

```
<table-for-listing-directive table-data="{{users}}"></table-for-listing-directive>
```

You may say, why didn't I put the tableData: "=" into the scope.
Well, after some long hours of searching I discovered that ng-repeat and scope{} don't want to work with each other, so in order to make the ng-repeat work inside the directive I have to say  'scope: true'.

Inside ng-repeat I tried to make  `ng-repeat="user in {{tableData}}"`  it doesn't work either.

Comment: This is the fiddle  :     http://jsfiddle.net/fiddle_gabriela/r6a0prjw/     If I put ng-repeat="user in users"  it will display the results but with the tableData  it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML change `table-data="{{users}}"` with `table-data="users"`